# angular move and select with arrow keys

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a search input that when typing call API and send a list of results. I want to that when stopping typing and push the arrow down key change focus from input to the results part and  move up and down on results by up/down arrow and do something on entering each of item

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> i hope this works , it will work according to your requirement.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" formControlName="ticketPriority" 
                     id="ticketPriority">
                        <option *ngFor="let data of datas" value={{data}}>
                        {{data}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
</div>
```